# Hibernate Lookup tables: As an Object Relation or as a code/key

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm, lookup-tables

So, I'm working on an application with lots of relations and lookup tables, but It all boils down to this:

**Person**

```
id INT (PK)
... (name, address, etc)
optcode VARCHAR (FK to Options)
typecode VARCHAR (FK to Types)
```

**Options**

```
optcode VARCHAR (PK)
optdesc VARCHAR
... (more meta data, like date added, etc)
```

**Types**

```
code VARCHAR (PK)
desc VARCHAR
... (more meta data, like date added, etc)
```

I'm using hibernate to access these tables and on the one hand, Object Relations have benefits, but on the other hand, just using Strings for the codes works better.

What is better Object Relations vs Keys vs both?

Just using Keys:

```
public class Person {
     private int id;
     ... (more attributes)
     private String optcode;
     private String typecode;
}
In the services:
Person person = new Person();
person.setOptcode("ABC");
person.setTypecode("XYZ");
session.save(person);
```

Or the O/R way:

```
public class Person {
     private int id;
     ... (more attributes)
     @JoinColumn
     private Options option;
     @JoinColumn
     private Types type;
}
In the services:
Person person = new Person();
person.setOption(new Options("ABC")); //Assume constructor fills in the 'optcode'
person.setType(new Types("XYZ"));     //Same, with 'code'
session.save(person);
```

In most cases of persistence, I only have the 'code', but many times when displaying the data it would be nice to show the 'desc'

Since I'll have a place to manage the Options and Types entities, those will exist anyways, but it just is annoying to have to wrap the 'code' in an object.

What do you think are the pros/cons of the different ways? What if I just put both into the Person object so i can use what ever is more convinent? What about making setters that just shove the string into a new Options/Types entity?

I'm trying to pin down the best way so it can be consistent, right now I've just been doing whatever required the least amount of new entities, but eventually everything will be represented by hibernate entities.

**Update:** The Person Entity will end up having almost 20 unique entity relations (each one pointing to a different table), The web-ui will probably have drop-down lists containing the values for each table, so I expect that I'll only have the 'code' to use for persistence. 
**Related:** I'm actually using a PersonImpl (plain POJO) and a PersonEntity (Hibernate Entity) and Dozer Mapping to go between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think entity relations make your coding easier, generally speaking, especially when querying for objects: what's easier than saying person.getOption().getDescription()? This approach does have drawbacks, however:

- Referenced entities have to be loaded from the DB, especially when you have save-cascade. In save-cascade, as you probably know, Hibernate will complain the object exists in the DB. I'm not sure what happens when you don't have save-cascade.
- Referenced entities have to be loaded with either a separate query, or an outer join on the loading of the main entity. *Can* cause performance problems.

Persisting the keys as mere properties can help in cases of complex relationships, for example when referencing a *big* entity with much loading to be done by Hibernate. This approach can help make loading the "master" entity lighter for the system. It does mean that *you* will have to do the entity loading yourself, if you need its properties. I'd say that for immutable "look-up" type entities, you could safely keep an in-memory Map of their instances and get() them by their key, instead of going to the DB. The down-side is that you will partition your entity-handling logic: you will have to remember which entities to cache and manage their caches.

I'd say that, in general, it's always better to work with entities, which is your model after all. Hibernate insists in noting that it helps you persist your object model to help you. It is only logical to delegate as much of the persistence stuff to Hibernate then. There *are* cases however, that Hibernate can't cope very well with a "proper" model: entities with many relations, "hot" entities that get used all the time, etc. In these cases, if Hibernate's mechanisms can't help (2nd level cache for example) you really have to resort to such "tricks" and do some of the work yourself.

Comment: Well, In the example i only have 2 relations, but in my application I'm well over a dozen, probably more like 20 relations in the worst case. I guess I see Entity relations as making the persistence of those codes harder, since on the UI-side it won't be dealing with objects, but only these codes.

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of an ORM is to give you an object graph, in which you can navigate, and which maps to a relational database. From a person, you should be able to get its option description using `person.getOption().getDescription()`.

You should also be able to search for persons with a given option date using

```
select p from Person p where p.option.date = :date
```

This is only possible if you map the foreign key as an association, rather than a String.

You should not use `new Option(code)` to put an existing option into your person, thouh. Instead, you should get or load the option from the session:

```
Person p = new Person();
p.setOption((Option) session.load(Option.class, "ABC"));
p.setType((Type) session.load(Type.class, "XYZ"));
session.save(p);

// and now, this code works as expected:
System.out.println(p.getOption().getDescription());
```

Comment: Having an object graph is an advantage sure, but when I do session.save(), it'll return the populated Entity. Also, I'm using Dozer to do bean mappings from Impls (non-hibernate) to Entities and back, so I'm going to run into issues there..

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll just use Hibernate's @MappedSuperclass for cases where tables have alot of the same structure ('code' ,'description', etc) so that I can keep the # of lines of code down. But otherwise O/R seems to be the way to go.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question because I was wondering what people were doing once they hit upon entities that required the lookup of other entities. The primary problem with that is that then you can no longer just create an instance, even in a test. My preferred approach is to move to either a Factory or an external (e.g. not static class) Builder.

The problem I have with this overall though is that it's very basic, and there is a lot of error-prone boilerplate involved. For example, suppose I have a piece of content, called Listing and I have to track the Source it came from (where I found it). The source is a very simple entity, but now that I have a reference to it inside Listing, I can no longer create Listings without doing the lookup of the source and then the injection of the appropriate one.

It would make sense, if possible, to handle this through simple annotations, e.g. something like mappedBy, but referring to either id or name, and then the container could do the lookup and the injection.

Doubt we'll see this anytime soon, though..